# AppleScript Error - Syntax Error

Tags: applescript, filemaker

I have Keyboard Maestro macros that call AppleScripts to open FileMaker Pro and open a specific file. This AppleScripts have worked for years but since the update to MacOS 12.5 from 12.4 they stoped working. I am now getting the error:

```
Expected end of line but found """.
```

The script is:

```
tell application "FileMaker Pro"
getURL "fmp://server/File.fmp12"
end tell
```

When running this in Script Editor, after clicking OK in the error dialog, it highlights the `"` just in front of `fmp:`.

Any clues what is different now?

Comment: Have you asked on KM forum? One of the later betas of 12.5 had serious AppleScript problems - maybe you are suffering from them not being completely fixed.

Comment: I have not because the problem wasn't just in KM. Same thing happened when just running the apple script.

Comment: Are you sure URL-use in the security properties of your File.fmp12 is set?